# How to enable input field based on another input field value in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJs form where I want to know the amount of hours worked. If the amount is `0`, I want to enable an extra question for the reason of not working.

```
<label>How many hours did you work?</label>
<input ng-model="hours" type="number" placeholder="8" />

<label ng-class="{'disabled-label': ifHoursZero}">Why didn't you work at all?</label>
<input ng-disabled="ifHoursZero" ng-model="reason" type="text" />
```

What is the elegant Angular way to toggle CSS and input fields with `ifHoursZero` if the `hours` value is `0`. Can this be done directly with the `hours` variable with some pattern?

Comment: you could use ```ng-show``` and ```ng-hide```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `ifHoursZero` a function that returns a boolean and call it like `ng-disabled="ifHoursZero()"`

For example:

```
function ifHoursZero() {
    return $scope.hours === 0;
}
```

See [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/cexipoputu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this without having to add a function to the controller:

```
<label>How many hours did you work?</label>
<input ng-model="hours" type="number" placeholder="8" />

<div ng-show="hours === 0">
  <label>Why didn't you work at all?</label>
  <input ng-model="reason" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Does the  `reason` variable bind at all if the ng-show hides it? And what if it shows it (by entering 0) and then hides it again (by entering >0)? Does it affect to its default scope values?

Comment: @Pekka it should be there hidden or not.. (enter 0 hours, type something, change hours to 1, reason should still be there) So in your controller you might want to check hours depending on what you're doing with reason.

Comment: what you have mentioned is about showing and hiding input field and not enabling or disabling it !